# Странные результаты метода .filter в javascript

Tags: javascript, массивы, методы

Добрый вечер. Это снова я и мой цирк вопросов )) Есть два массива - массив объектов и просто массив чисел:

```
var numbers1 = [{prop: 1},{prop: 2},{prop: 3},{prop: 4},{prop: 5},{prop: 6}];
var numbers2 = [2,3,4,6];
```

Почему .filter над numbers1 в такой редакции:

```
var mynumbers = numbers1.filter(function(number1) {
    var bufferNumber;
    numbers2.forEach(function(number2) {
        if (number1.prop == number2)
        {
            bufferNumber = number1;
            return bufferNumber;
        }
    });

    return bufferNumber;
});
```

выдает в консоль ожидаемое `[ { prop: 2 }, { prop: 3 }, { prop: 4 }, { prop: 6 } ]`, а вариант без объявления буфферной переменной:

```
var mynumbers = numbers1.filter(function(number1) {
    numbers2.forEach(function(number2) {
        if (number1.prop == number2)
            return number1;
    });

    return number1;
});
```

не фильтрует массив numbers1, а возвращает его неотфильтрованный вариант

```
[ { prop: 1 },
  { prop: 2 },
  { prop: 3 },
  { prop: 4 },
  { prop: 5 },
  { prop: 6 } ]
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все очень просто: если коллбэк, переданный в функцию `filter`, возвращает результат соответствующий `true` - элемент помещается в результат, если `false` - не помещается.

В примере, в массиве `numbers` содержаться объекты, которые всегда соответствуют `true`, поэтому во втором примере, если выкинуть из него внутренний цикл, который ни на что не влияет получим

```
var mynumbers = numbers1.filter(function(number1) {
    return number1;
});
```

откуда видно, что возвращая элемент этого массива, все элементы *удовлетворяют* условию и помещаются в результат.

С первым случаем ситуация интереснее.

Во-первых, возвращается временная переменная, она объявлена внутри функции коллбэка, и на каждой итерации своя.

Во-вторых, значение ей присваивается в зависимости от условия, и в противном случае является *undefined*, который соответствует *false*, поэтому в случае если значение свойства не было найдено значение переменной осталось *undefiend* и проверяемый элемент массива не заносился в результат.

<sub>**небольшое отступление:** `return` внутри коллбэка переданного функции `forEach` не прерывает обход коллекции. В данном случае проще проверять вхождение с помощью [функции indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) или [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)</sub>

```js
var numbers1 = [{
  prop: 1
}, {
  prop: 2
}, {
  prop: 3
}, {
  prop: 4
}, {
  prop: 5
}, {
  prop: 6
}];
var numbers2 = [2, 3, 4, 6];
document.write('temp variable:', '<br>')
var mynumbers = numbers1.filter(function(number1) {
  var bufferNumber;
  numbers2.forEach(function(number2) {
    if (number1.prop == number2) {
      bufferNumber = number1;
      return bufferNumber;
    }
  });
  document.write('el:', JSON.stringify(number1), '->', !!bufferNumber, '<br>');
  return bufferNumber;
});
document.write('result: ', JSON.stringify(mynumbers), '<br>');

document.write('<br>', 'without temp variable:', '<br>')
var mynumbers = numbers1.filter(function(number1) {
  numbers2.forEach(function(number2) {
    if (number1.prop == number2)
      return number1;
  });
  document.write('el:', JSON.stringify(number1), '->', !!number1, '<br>');
  return number1;
});
document.write('result: ', JSON.stringify(mynumbers), '<br>');
document.write('<br>', 'with indexOf:', '<br>')
var mynumbers = numbers1.filter(function(number1) {

  document.write('el:', JSON.stringify(number1), '->', numbers2.indexOf(number1.prop) > -1, '<br>');
  return numbers2.indexOf(number1.prop) > -1;
});
document.write('result: ', JSON.stringify(mynumbers), '<br>');

document.write('<br>', 'with some function:', '<br>')
var mynumbers = numbers1.filter(function(number1) {

  document.write('el:', JSON.stringify(number1), '->', numbers2.some(function(num) {
    return num == number1.prop
  }), '<br>');
  return numbers2.some(function(num) {
    return num == number1.prop
  });
});
document.write('result: ', JSON.stringify(mynumbers), '<br>');
```

Comment: а почему во втором варианте проверочный `.forEach` по второму массиву ни на что не влияет?

Comment: @AntonFoigt, потому что, он ничего не делает: пробежался по коллекции numbers2, выполняя или не выполняя условие и никак не меняя состояние функции снаружи

Comment: @AntonFoigt, перед сниппетом, есть небольшое отступление по поводу `forEach`